# Assigning ID values to names in a list

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I have a list that contains date, ID, and coordinates. I have another list with just values. I would like to assign the ID from one list to the list names.

For example:
I would like to get assign the `ID` values from the split `ID` list in `df1` to the parts labelled `[[1]]`,`[[2]]`,`[[3]]`,`[[4]]`,`[[5]]` in list `l`.

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

date <- rep_len(seq(dmy("01-01-2010"), dmy("31-12-2013"), by = "days"),1000)
ID <- rep(c("A","B","C", "D", "E"), 100)

df <- data.frame(date = date,
                 x = runif(length(date), min = 60000, max = 80000),
                 y = runif(length(date), min = 800000, max = 900000),
                 ID)

df1 <- df %>% group_split(ID)

l <- list(1,2,3,4,5)
```

Comment: Do you mean to use `setNames() ` at the end of the df split?

Comment: I mean do you want to set names for df1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we need to change the names

```
names(df1) <- unlist(l)
```

---

The `l` is a `list` of values.  If we need to extract the 'ID' from 'df1'

```
library(purrr)
l <- map(df1, ~ .x$ID)
```

-output

```
l
[[1]]
  [1] "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A"
 [32] "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A"
 [63] "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A"
 [94] "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A"
[125] "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A"
[156] "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A"
[187] "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A"

[[2]]
  [1] "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B"
 [32] "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B"
 [63] "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B"
 [94] "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B"
[125] "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B"
[156] "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B"
[187] "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B"

[[3]]
  [1] "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C"
 [32] "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C"
 [63] "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C"
 [94] "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C"
[125] "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C"
[156] "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C"
[187] "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C"

[[4]]
  [1] "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D"
 [32] "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D"
 [63] "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D"
 [94] "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D"
[125] "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D"
[156] "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D"
[187] "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D"

[[5]]
  [1] "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E"
 [32] "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E"
 [63] "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E"
 [94] "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E"
[125] "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E"
[156] "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E"
[187] "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E"
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the `.x$ID` part in the argument. What does the `.x` stand for?

Comment: @JohnHuang it is anonymous function in tidyverse which is a short form for `function(x) x` where `x` is the element of the list i.e. a data.frame

Comment: I've been getting the error `Corrupt x: no names` when I run the `map` function. What could be the cause of this?

Comment: @JohnHuang is the error based on the same data showed.  I did tested that and it was not showing any error for this.  Here `df1` is a `list` of dataset.  Are you running this on `df` which is a single dataset

Comment: Yeah, its on the same dataset `df1`.

Comment: @JohnHuang I couldn't reproduce the error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232527/discussion-between-john-huang-and-akrun).

Comment: I am in the chat room

Answer (score 2):

Do you need this?

```
df %>% group_split(ID) %>% setNames(c("A","B","C", "D", "E"))
```